# Finding supersingular elliptic curves over $\Bbb F_p$ with rational endomorphisms of degree 3 using Deuring correspondence

Tags: algebraic-geometry, elliptic-curves, quaternions, sagemath, isogeny

I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4370619/1074276) on this website, which gives a code that almost does what I want. Basically, I am looking for supersingular elliptic curves $E/\mathbb F_p$ that have endomorphisms of degree 3, 6 or (worst case) 9, such that those endomorphisms' kernel consists of points defined over $\mathbb F_p$. I thought about using Deuring correspondence to do so, by designing a suitable maximal quaternion order and then finding a corresponding elliptic curve. This is very close to what [the code here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4370619/1074276) does :

```
def j_with_embedding(p, q):
  F = GF(p) 
  R.<x> = PolynomialRing(F) 
  K = QuadraticField(-q) 
  o = K.maximal_order() 
  d = o.discriminant() 
  H = hilbert_class_polynomial(d)
  return R(H).roots(multiplicities=False)
```

so I tried to run it while keeping $q = 3$, but for the endomorphisms that I find, the condition that the kernel has only points in $\mathbb F_p$ is never satisfied. I guess this is because the criteria "E must have an endomorphism $\phi$ such that $\phi^2 = [-3]$" is too restrictive.

I thought about changing q = 3 for q = -3, but I get an error at the line

```
H = hilbert_class_polynomial(d)
```

which is

```
D (=12) must be negative
```

How can I adapt this code to get the j-invariants at the end ?

Thanks in advance :)